# How can Perl fill out fields on a GUI made in Visual Basic?

Tags: perl, user-interface, scripting, automation

I have a script that runs several little programs I don't have the source code to, one of which requires filling out some fields in a GUI. I've been doing this by hand, but I'd like to have the Perl script focus the GUI window, then enter some hardcoded text into each field and close the window.

Answer (score 4):

In the past I've used the [Win32::GuiTest](http://search.cpan.org/~karasik/Win32-GuiTest/) module for tasks like this. Have a look at the [example scripts](http://search.cpan.org/~karasik/Win32-GuiTest/lib/Win32/GuiTest/Examples.pm) and [documentation](http://www.piotrkaluski.com/files/winguitest/docs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Unless there's a specific reason you're using Perl, [Autoit](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/index.shtml) is a Basic-like scripting language pretty much specifically designed for automating GUI tasks.  It's very easy to pick up.

You can have it wait for a window to become active, send any sequence of keystrokes or tell it to specifically focus on a GUI element with a given handle, and much more.  You can also package the scripts as standalone executables, which can be a nice benefit when you need it.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into [Win32::OLE](http://search.cpan.org/~jdb/Win32-OLE-0.1709/lib/Win32/OLE.pm).  There's also [a book on this topic](http://www.perl.com/pub/a/2005/04/21/win32ole.html).